# Build fails on Jenkins but works in Eclipse

Tags: jenkins, ant

I got a Spring project built using Ant that fails when executed on Jenkins, but not when I run the exact same Ant target from Eclipse (Ant view).

Jenkins version is **2.19.4**

**Jenkins Console Output excerpt**

```
Started by user Morin, Charles
Building in workspace D:\APPS\jenkins-2.19.4\workspace\MY-PROJECT
Using locally configured password for connection to :pserver:MY-SERVICE-ACCOUNT@MY-CVS-SERVER:D:/DATA/REPOSITORIES/MY-CVS-REPO
cvs update -d -P -r HEAD -D 26 Jan 2017 10:09:39 -0500 MY-PROJECT 
Using locally configured password for connection to :pserver:MY-SERVICE-ACCOUNT@MY-CVS-SERVER:D:/DATA/REPOSITORIES/MY-CVS-REPO
cvs rlog -S -d25 Jan 2017 00:08:54 -0500<26 Jan 2017 10:09:39 -0500 MY-PROJECT 
[MY-PROJECT] $ cmd.exe /C "D:\APPS\jenkins-2.19.4\ant\bin\ant.bat -file build.xml compile && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
Buildfile: build.xml
     [echo] ========================================================================
     [echo] *** Starting MY-PROJECT build 
     [echo] ========================================================================

print-version:
     [echo] Java/JVM version: 1.6
     [echo] Java/JVM detailed version: 1.7.0_25

create-directories:

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 41 source files to D:\APPS\jenkins-2.19.4\workspace\MY-PROJECT\target\classes
    [javac] Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.1.0.Final
    [javac] D:\APPS\jenkins-2.19.4\workspace\MY-PROJECT\src\path\to\my\class\MyClass.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import path.to.my.class.MyClass_;
    [javac]                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class MyClass_
    [javac]   location: package path.to.my.class
```

The problem is that my JPA metamodels are not being found during the compilation. However, we can see the following line that confirms the generation of JPA Metamodels:

```
Note: Hibernate JPA 2 Static-Metamodel Generator 5.1.0.Final
```

The only difference I can see is in the print-version Ant target. When executed locally, I got this:

```
print-version:
     [echo] Java/JVM version: 1.7
     [echo] Java/JVM detailed version: 1.7.0_25
```

I also have several other projects with the exact same setup, and I don't have that issue.

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<project name="MY-PROJECT" default="create-war-and-deploy-to-jboss" basedir="." xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

    <property name="verbose" value="false" />
    <property name="javaVersion" value="1.7" />

    <!-- Provides access to OS environment variables (eg: env.USERNAME) -->
    <property environment="env" />

    <!-- Application's directories -->
    <property name="dir.build" value="${basedir}/build" />
    <property name="dir.src" value="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="dir.dist" value="${basedir}/dist" />
    <property name="dir.lib" location="${basedir}/lib" />
    <property name="dir.target" value="${basedir}/target" />
    <property name="dir.build.classes" value="${dir.target}/classes" />
    <property name="dir.test" value="${basedir}/test" />
    <property name="dir.web" value="${basedir}/WebContent" />
    <property name="dir.webinf.lib" value="${dir.web}/WEB-INF/lib" />

    <!-- Loading the application.properties file -->
    <property file="${dir.src}/resources/application.properties" prefix="app." />

    <!-- Loading the build.properties file -->
    <property file="build.properties" prefix="buildProp." />

    <tstamp>
        <format property="build.time" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" />
    </tstamp>

    <echo message="========================================================================" />
    <echo message="*** Starting ${app.name} build " />
    <echo message="========================================================================" />

    <!-- JBoss directories -->
    <property name="dir.jboss" value="${buildProp.jboss.home}" />
    <property name="dir.jboss.domain" value="${dir.jboss}/${buildProp.jboss.domain}" />
    <property name="dir.jboss.libs" value="${dir.jboss}/${buildProp.jboss.libs}" />
    <property name="dir.jboss.deploy" value="${dir.jboss.domain}/${buildProp.jboss.deploy}" />

    <!-- Path for unit tests -->
    <path id="run.classpath.tests">
        <pathelement path="${dir.build.classes}" />
        <pathelement path="${dir.test}/build/classes" />
        <path refid="compile.classpath.tests" />
    </path>

    <!-- Provided dependencies from the container -->
    <path id="compile.classpath.server">
        <fileset dir="${dir.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Dependencies specific to this application -->
    <path id="compile.classpath.web">
        <fileset dir="${dir.web}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="compile.classpath.target">
        <fileset dir="${dir.lib}">
            <include name="hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.1.0.Final.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${dir.target}">
            <include name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Dependencies specifically for unit testing purposes -->
    <path id="compile.classpath.tests">
        <fileset dir="${dir.test}/lib/">
            <include name="junit-4.6.jar" />
            <include name="mockito-all-1.9.5.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${dir.webinf.lib}" />
        <pathelement location="${dir.build.classes}" />
        <path refid="compile.classpath.server" />
    </path>

    <!-- PRINT-VERSION -->
    <target name="print-version"> 
       <echo>Java/JVM version: ${ant.java.version}</echo> 
       <echo>Java/JVM detailed version: ${java.version}</echo> 
    </target>

    <!-- BUILD-DISTRIBUTION -->
    <target 
        name="build-distribution" 
        description="Generate Deployment unit and stage to appserver directory." 
        depends="
            clean,
            run-unit-tests,
            create-war,
            run-sonarqube-analysis">

        <manifest file="${dir.web}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
            <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />
            <attribute name="Ant-Version" value="1.7.0" />
            <attribute name="Created-By" value="${env.USERNAME}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${app.name}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${app.version}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="Canada Revenue Agency" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Date" value="${build.time}" />
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${env.USERNAME}" />
            <attribute name="Dependencies" value="org.hibernate" />
        </manifest>

        <propertyfile file="${dir.src}/resources/application.properties">
            <entry key="lastUpdate" value="${build.time}" />
        </propertyfile>

    </target>

    <!-- CLEAN -->
    <target name="clean" 
        description="Cleans up build-related temporary directories." 
        depends="delete-directories" />

    <!-- CREATE-DIRECTORIES -->
    <target name="create-directories" >
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.dist}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build.classes}" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.web}/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test}/build" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test}/build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.test}/reports" />
    </target>

    <!-- DELETES-DIRECTORIES -->
    <target name="delete-directories">

        <delete dir=".sonar" />

        <!-- /build -->
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.build}" includes="**/*" />
            <exclude name=".cvsignore" />
        </delete>

        <!-- /dist -->
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.dist}" includes="**/*" />
            <exclude name=".cvsignore" />
        </delete>

        <!-- /WEB-INF/classes -->
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.web}/WEB-INF/classes">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${dir.web}/WEB-INF/src">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>
        </delete>

        <!-- /target -->
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.target}" includes="**/*" />
            <exclude name=".cvsignore" />
        </delete>

        <!-- /test/build -->
        <delete dir="${dir.test}/build" />

        <!-- /test/reports -->
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${dir.test}/reports" />
        </delete>

        <!-- Existing WAR file and JBoss marker files -->
        <delete dir="${dir.jboss.deploy}/${app.name}.war" />
        <delete file="${dir.jboss.deploy}/${app.name}.war" />
        <delete file="${dir.jboss.deploy}/${app.name}.war.deployed" />
    </target>

    <!-- COMPILE -->
    <target name="compile" depends="print-version,create-directories">
        <javac destdir="${dir.build.classes}" verbose="${verbose}" debug="on" fork="true" failonerror="true" source="${javaVersion}" target="${javaVersion}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="compile.classpath.server" />
                <path refid="compile.classpath.target" />
                <path refid="compile.classpath.web" />
            </classpath>
            <src path="${dir.src}" />

            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
        </javac>

        <!--copy property files to classes directory -->
        <copy todir="${dir.build.classes}">
            <fileset dir="${dir.src}">
                <include name="**/*.properties" />
                <include name="META-INF/**/*" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <!-- COMPILE-TESTS -->
    <target name="compile-tests" depends="create-directories,compile">
        <javac srcdir="${dir.test}/src" destdir="${dir.test}/build/classes" verbose="${verbose}" debug="on" fork="true" source="${javaVersion}" target="${javaVersion}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath.tests" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- RUN-UNIT-TESTS -->
    <target name="run-unit-tests" depends="compile-tests" description="Runs all unit test classes under the test package.">

        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
            <classpath path="test/lib/org.jacoco.ant-0.7.2.201409121644.jar"/>
            <classpath path="test/lib/org.jacoco.agent_0.7.2.201409121644.jar"/>
            <classpath path="test/lib/org.jacoco.core_0.7.2.201409121644.jar"/>
            <classpath path="test/lib/org.jacoco.report_0.7.2.201409121644.jar"/>
        </taskdef>

        <jacoco:coverage destfile="${dir.target}/jacoco.exec">
            <junit fork="true" printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="no">
                <classpath refid="run.classpath.tests" />
                <formatter type="xml" />
                <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${dir.test}/reports">
                    <fileset dir="${dir.test}/src">
                        <include name="**/*Test.java" />
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>

    <!-- CREATE-WAR -->
    <target name="create-war" description="Creates a WAR file including all compiled classes and resources." depends="compile">
        <war destfile="dist/${app.name}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent" />
            <classes dir="${dir.build.classes}" />
        </war>
    </target>

    <!-- CREATE-WAR-AND-DEPLOY -->
    <target name="create-war-and-deploy-to-jboss" description="Creates a WAR file including all compiled classes and resources, and deploys the app to jboss" depends="create-war,deploy-to-jboss" />

    <!-- RUN-SONARQUBE -->
    <target name="run-sonarqube-analysis" description="Runs the SonarQube analysis and updates statistics on the server." depends="create-war">

        <property file="sonar.properties" prefix="sonar." />

        <!-- SonarQube properties -->
        <property name="sonar.exclusions" value="${sonar.exclusions}" />
        <property name="sonar.host.url" value="${sonar.host.url}" />
        <property name="sonar.jacoco.reportPath" value="${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}" />
        <property name="sonar.java.binaries" value="${sonar.java.binaries}" />
        <property name="sonar.java.coveragePlugin" value="${sonar.java.coveragePlugin}" />
        <property name="sonar.java.libraries" value="${sonar.java.libraries}" />
        <property name="sonar.java.source" value="${javaVersion}" />
        <property name="sonar.junit.reportsPath" value="${sonar.junit.reportsPath}" />
        <property name="sonar.projectKey" value="${sonar.projectKey}" />
        <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="${app.version}" />
        <property name="sonar.projectName" value="${sonar.projectName}" />
        <property name="sonar.sources" value="${sonar.sources}" />
        <property name="sonar.sourceEncoding" value="${sonar.sources.sourceEncoding}" />
        <property name="sonar.tests" value="${sonar.tests}" />

        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            <classpath path="${dir.lib}/sonarqube-ant-task-2.4.1.jar" />
        </taskdef>

        <sonar:sonar/>
    </target>

    <!-- DEPLOY-TO-JBOSS -->
    <target name="deploy-to-jboss" depends="create-war">

        <!--delete war file if it already exists and was copied over, we need a directory now-->
        <delete file="${dir.jboss.deploy}/${app.name}.war" />
        <delete file="${dir.jboss.deploy}/${app.name}.war.deployed" />

        <!-- copy all of the files except one that will trigger the deployment -->
        <copy todir="${dir.jboss.deploy}">
            <fileset file="${dir.dist}/${app.name}.war" />
        </copy>

    </target>
</project>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From Manage Jenkins-->Configure System--JDK section, add both JDKs to JDK Installation. From your Job Configuration, in the JDK section, explicitly choose the 1.7 JDK.

Comment: Did you mean Global Tool Configuration? I don't have anything related to JDK under "Configure System".

Comment: What would be the benefits of adding the other JDK? Any way to make Jenkins use the same JDK (1.7). I'm trying to find how to set Jenkins (or Ant?) to use JDK 1.7u25 for all jobs.

Comment: Only in case you need to use that some day. :-)  I had run across the same issue (but in my case I needed the 1.8 JDK and it was picking up 1.7). If you explicitly define the path to the JDK for your 1.7, it will use. that. I did not mean Global Tool Configuration, but if that is the ONLY JDK you will ever use, yes, you can use that.